# How to configure "return-key-skip" behaviour in IntelliJ?

Tags: css, intellij-idea

How do I get from here:

[image]

to here:

[image]

by only pressing `return`?

This is a `css` file. I searched the `Editor/codestyle/css` settings for it but didn't find anything. Is there an option for the `"return-key-skip"` behaviour in `IntelliJ`?

Comment: The default shortcut is Ctrl + Shift + Enter". You can try to assign a custom shortcut for "Complete Current Statement" under "Settings / Preferences | Keymap", and reassign a shortcut for "Enter" to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov thanks! You're the man. The "complete current statement" command was what I was looking for. Additionally I found out that this works not only with Ctrl + Shift + Enter but also with the more simple Shift + Enter. I don't know why, but it works.